# Простой многопоточный (асинхронный) сервер на TcpListener

Tags: c#, tcp-ip, сервер

Уже несколько раз пытался написать многопоточный сервер обрабатывающий сообщения от клиентов асинхронно, но где-то получается либо утечка памяти, либо он подвисает после приема первого же подключения (в ***Process Explorer*** видно что число входящих подключений увеличивается, но они висят не закрытыми).

Нашел пример - "**[Создание TCP/IP сервера на C#](http://round-angle-net.blogspot.com/2010/09/tcpip-c.html)**". Но ни как не могу разобраться с ним.

По сути мне нужен сервер на подобии "*Версия 3*" из примера. Т.е. сервер должен ждать входящих подключений от клиентов, которые сразу начинают передавать данные (строку, например). Сервер должен быть в состоянии обслужить несколько входящих подключений, желательно для этого не создавать потоки, а обрабатывать подключения асинхронно. Данные переданные от клиента то же лучше читать асинхронно, так как длина строки не определена и может быть достаточно большой. После завершения чтения данных нужно сразу передать один байт - типа флаг, данные приняты. После передачи байта клиенту соединение нужно закрыть.

Кто-нибудь может привести небольшой пример ***TCP/IP*** сервера на *C#* на основе ***TcpListener*** ?

Comment: На хабре была статья по этому поводу года 1,5 назад: [Многопоточный сервер на C# за 15 минут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/120157/).

Comment: Неужели больше нет вариантов ?

Comment: Знаю библиотеку на С++ ProstoServer. 

http://prostoserver.com/index.php

работает на "Input/Output Completion Port (IOCP) mechanism" что есть в windows. 

Вот статья о IOCP в C#

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10280/Managed-I-O-Completion-Ports-IOCP

Может поможет чем то.

Comment: На текущий момент (2018 год) задача тривиально решается при помощи async/await.

Answer (score -1):

Если еще кому-то актуально - отличный пример асинхронного(async/await) сервера с клиентом на [Metanit](https://metanit.com/sharp/net/4.4.php)

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

ServerObject server = new ServerObject();// создаем сервер
await server.ListenAsync(); // запускаем сервер

class ServerObject
{
    TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8888); // сервер для прослушивания
    List<ClientObject> clients = new List<ClientObject>(); // все подключения
protected internal void RemoveConnection(string id)
{
    // получаем по id закрытое подключение
    ClientObject? client = clients.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
    // и удаляем его из списка подключений
    if (client != null) clients.Remove(client);
    client?.Close();
}
// прослушивание входящих подключений
protected internal async Task ListenAsync()
{
    try
    {
        tcpListener.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Сервер запущен. Ожидание подключений...");

        while (true)
        {
            TcpClient tcpClient = await tcpListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();

            ClientObject clientObject = new ClientObject(tcpClient, this);
            clients.Add(clientObject);
            Task.Run(clientObject.ProcessAsync);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        Disconnect();
    }
}

// трансляция сообщения подключенным клиентам
protected internal async Task BroadcastMessageAsync(string message, string id)
{
    foreach (var client in  clients)
    {
        if (client.Id != id) // если id клиента не равно id отправителя
        {
            await client.Writer.WriteLineAsync(message); //передача данных
            await client.Writer.FlushAsync();
        }
    }
}
// отключение всех клиентов
protected internal void Disconnect()
{
    foreach (var client in clients)
    {
        client.Close(); //отключение клиента
    }
    tcpListener.Stop(); //остановка сервера
}
}
```